# A starting point on making 3d animation in React Native?

Tags: 3d, react

I am making an app using react native and I need to make an 3D animation

The animation is similar to game of throne intro or google map when you zoom in and all the buildings become 3D and raise up from the ground.

I've used react native animatable for 2D animation but I am unsure how to even start this.

I was hoping there is an example similar to what I am thinking or a template/library that I can use

Any recommendations?